# is there a way to use mstest in my application

Tags: .net, mstest

is there a way to run mstests inside my application ?

these how it should work i should put the project in a folder point my appliaton to it and  run the tests

thx for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know [the Galio project](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/) have it on their roadmap to create a testrunner for MSTest and that there is already [source in the project](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#--kv20-JHyI/v3/src/Extensions/MSTest/Gallio.MSTestRunner/GallioTestAdapter.cs&q=mstest%20package%3Ahttp%3A//mb-unit.googlecode.com) for an MSTest extension. Don't know the state of this though but it could be useful to have a look into it.